# Is there any tutorial about Local Push Connectivity on iOS?

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I would like to find some tutorials about how to implement [Local Push Connectivity](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/local_push_connectivity) in iOS. I researched in Apple forums, documentation... I only found the [SimplePush example](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/local_push_connectivity/receiving_voice_and_text_communications_on_a_local_network) provided by Apple. With the last example, I couldn't found a way to implement the [NEAppPushProvider](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/neapppushprovider) and the [NEAppPushManager](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/neapppushmanager), and I would be very grateful if you have any more example. Furthermore, I tried to request the [entitlement for NetworkExtension app-push-provider](https://developer.apple.com/contact/request/local-push-connectivity) but the web said to me that I am unauthorized to request it, while for other entitlements it doesn't happen (I am using a Developer Account with all privileges).